# MySQL group each row to be part of multiple groups

Tags: mysql, average

I want to make a requests to make a AVG of some data. For example if I got

Table1:

```
Col1 Col2
 1    1
 2    2
 3    3
```

I want to group the like so:

```
GRP Col1 Col2
 1    1    1
 12   2    2
 23   3    3
```

So the middle row will be grouped for both 1st and the 3rd row
And when you do the average you got:

```
Col1 Col2
1.5   1.5
2.5   2.5
```

At this point I got something like (i change it a bit so it will make sense):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getAverage;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE getAverage ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE current INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    SET current := startDate - (step * (quantity - 1));
    SET endDate := endDate - (step * (quantity - 1));

    WHILE current < endDate DO
        SET @i := 0;
        SELECT
            FROM_UNIXTIME(MIN(date)),
            FORMAT(AVG(field_0), 2) AS field_0,
            FORMAT(AVG(field_1), 2) AS field_1
        FROM (
            SELECT
                table1.date,
                field_0,
                field_1
            FROM table1
        ) 
        AS Q1;

            SET current := current + step;
        END WHILE;

    END //

    DELIMITER ;
```

In other words I need to group records from 1 to 24, from 2 to 25 and so on. I have no clue how to make it possible, beside the procedure above.

EDIT:
I see that it was not explained well. So I got N records in a table. I want to get the average from 1 to M in a row, then from 2 to M+1, 3 to M+2, ..., i to M+i. So each record is in a group with M-1 other rows.
At the example with `GRP` I meant so there will be groups like '1', '2', '3', and so on. So if I say group by `GRP` it will take the 2nd row for more then 1 row. Like it wont be like GRP will be '0' for M records and use those row, but it will use each row for M averages. If that makes sense.
The result for the table above will be will be something like:

```
1.5 1.5
2.5 2.5
```

With N = 3 and M = 2;
This is used for yearly reference of a organisations. (I am not sure if that is the 'term').

I could easily do it with PHP so it will say 'give me the average from K to L' then K++ and L++; where K-L = M but I am pretty sure SQL can do it much faster.

Thank you for you time guys!

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand the logic here. I suspect that a 3-row data set is not going to be fairly representative of the problem

Comment: I tried to explain it better in the edit. I still do not think its perfect, but I can not think of better way to explain it. Its that you got N records and you want average for each M, but starting from K, ending at L, which does not increment each iteration by M, but with 1.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your example really makes very little sense, so here's something to consider instead...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,x INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (x) VALUES(12),(24),(36);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+----+
| id | x  |
+----+----+
|  1 | 12 |
|  2 | 24 |
|  3 | 36 |
+----+----+

SELECT 2*(CEILING(id/2)) n, AVG(x) average FROM my_table GROUP BY n;
+------+---------+
| n    | average |
+------+---------+
|    2 | 18.0000 |
|    4 | 36.0000 |
+------+---------+
```

Comment: As far as I can see this makes an average for each M records. That is not exactly what I was searching for. I've updated the post, so it makes more sense I hope.

Thanks you!